# JSOUP parsing two table

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

I have parsed the first table but I don't know how to parse the second table.

```html
    <div class="catItemHeader" style="position: absolute;">
    <h3 class="catItemTitle" style="color: #982C37;font-size: 30px;font-weight: 600;">Arrivi</h3>

    <div style="color: #982C37; margin-left: 104px;margin-top: -20px;font-weight: bold;">
        <label>Ultimo aggiornamento:</label> 17/04/2014 10:12   </div>
    <table class="tabella-voli">
        <thead>
            <th>Compagnia</th>
            <th>N.</th>
            <th>Provenienza</th>
            <th>Schedulato</th>
            <th>Stimato</th>
            <th>Stato</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                        <tr style="background-color: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.8);">
                <td>RYANAIR</td>
                <td>03071</td>
                <td>Londra Stansted</td>
                <td>17/04/2014 12:40</td>
                <td>17/04/2014 12:32</td>
                <td>
                                        <img src="/images/volo_green.gif"  alt="In orario" title="In orario"/><br /> In orario              </td>
            </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.8);">
                <td>RYANAIR</td>
                <td>04075</td>
                <td>Kaunas</td>
                <td>17/04/2014 16:10</td>
                <td>17/04/2014 16:10</td>
                <td>
                                        <img src="/images/volo_green.gif"  alt="In orario" title="In orario"/><br /> In orario              </td>
            </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.8);">
                <td>RYANAIR</td>
                <td>07316</td>
                <td>Dublino</td>
                <td>17/04/2014 20:45</td>
                <td>17/04/2014 20:45</td>
                <td>
                                        <img src="/images/volo_green.gif"  alt="In orario" title="In orario"/><br /> In orario              </td>
            </tr>
                    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="catItemHeader" style="margin-left: 438px;">
    <h3 class="catItemTitle" style="color: #982C37;font-size: 30px;font-weight: 600;">Partenze</h3>

    <div style="color: #982C37;margin-left: 158px;margin-top: -20px;font-weight: bold;">
        <label>Ultimo aggiornamento:</label> 17/04/2014 10:12   </div>
    <table class="tabella-voli">
        <thead>
            <th>Compagnia</th>
            <th>N.</th>
            <th>Destinazione</th>
            <th>Schedulato</th>
            <th>Stimato</th>
            <th>Stato</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                        <tr style="background-color: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.8);">
                <td>RYANAIR</td>
                <td>03074</td>
                <td>Londra Stansted</td>
                <td>17/04/2014 13:05</td>
                <td>17/04/2014 13:05</td>
                <td>
                                        <img src="/images/volo_green.gif" alt="In orario" title="In orario"/><br /> In orario               </td>
            </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.8);">
                <td>RYANAIR</td>
                <td>04076</td>
                <td>Kaunas</td>
                <td>17/04/2014 16:35</td>
                <td>17/04/2014 16:35</td>
                <td>
                                        <img src="/images/volo_green.gif" alt="In orario" title="In orario"/><br /> In orario               </td>
            </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.8);">
                <td>RYANAIR</td>
                <td>07317</td>
                <td>Dublino</td>
                <td>17/04/2014 21:10</td>
                <td>17/04/2014 21:10</td>
                <td>
                                        <img src="/images/volo_green.gif" alt="In orario" title="In orario"/><br /> In orario               </td>
            </tr>
                    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

 </div>
            </div>
                </div>

</div>
```

The first table parsed with:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://site.eu").timeout(7*1000).get();

org.jsoup.nodes.Element tabella = doc.getElementsByClass("tabella-voli").first();
Iterator<org.jsoup.nodes.Element> iterator = tabella.select("td").iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
```

Can you help me with parsing ONLY the second table? I want only td elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate an Elements class instead on directly invoque "first()" on it.
Then you will be able to parse the table you wish with the "get(int)" method:

```
Elements tables = currentServerPage.getElementsByClass("tabella-voli");
Element secondTable = tables.get(1);
Elements tdElements = currentServerPage.getElementsByTag("td");
```

Then you'll get a list of Elements, containing all the "td" in the second table.

Comment: If you want to use an Iterator on the "td" list, then , you just have to do the same thing as before: "Iterator<org.jsoup.nodes.Element> iterator = tdElements.iterator();", even if I don't understand why you ABSOLUTELY need it : there are many ways to iterate over collections...

Comment: iterator is good why i use a while() for arrive at the end.. other solutions?

Comment: You can use a "for(Element tempElement : elements)" or even "for(int index = 0; index<elements.size(); index++)". In the second case, you will be able to know which table you are working on (with the index).

Comment: org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://sss.eu").timeout(7*1000).get();
               
               Elements tables = currentServerPage.getElementsByClass("tabella-voli");
               Element secondTable = tables.get(1);
               Elements tdElements = currentServerPage.getElementsByTag("td");

               for(Element tempElement : tdElements){
                              thread++;
                              System.out.println(tdElements);
is wrong

Comment: Shouldn't "System.out.println(tdElements)" be "System.out.println(tempElement)" instead?

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped you ;)